# Light Not Rendering - Cycles

Tags: light

I am trying to render a house with cycles, and for some reason, it will not render the light. The .blend file is below.

I have a plane which I am using to emit light using the Emission feature of the surface property in materials. When I render the project, the image does not render the light which is supposed to emit from the plane

[image]

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2732" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2732/)

Comment: In the future please use the [edit] link to modify your post. Also add a detailed description of your issue along with images that show your current settings. Not all issues require folks to download the file to figure out a solution.

Comment: I have a plane which I am using to emit light using the Emission feature of the surface property in materials. When I render the project, the image does not render the light which is supposed to emit from the plane.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add information to the question. (between share and close)

Answer (score 1):

The emission shader is not assigned to the mesh.

Enter edit mode, select the emitter plane, select the material and click on assign:

[image]